# NO_SINGLE_MAIL_PERMISSION, Single email is not enabled for your organization or profile.: []

Tags: send-email

Tried to send an email from salesforce apex and got the below error.

Getting error as **FATAL_ERROR System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: NO_SINGLE_MAIL_PERMISSION, Single email is not enabled for your organization or profile.: []**

````
    public static void sendEmail(String htmlBody, String subject,String toAddresses,String ccAddresses,String bccAddresses){
        System.debug('htmlBody:'+htmlBody);
        System.debug('subject:'+subject);
        System.debug('toAddresses:'+toAddresses);
        System.debug('ccAddresses:'+ccAddresses);
        System.debug('bccAddresses:'+bccAddresses);
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
       mail.setSubject(subject);
       mail.setToAddresses(new List<String>{'verma366d@gmail.com'});
    //    mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
    //    mail.setBccAddresses(bccAddresses);

        Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{mail});
    }```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the [Email Deliverability](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_email_deliverability.htm&type=5) is off. Please set it to `All email`.

To set it, from Setup, enter *Deliverability* in the Quick Find box, and then select **Deliverability**.

Comment: Thanks Saroj,

I checked my email deliverability was set to system emails only changed it to all emails and issue is resolved. 

Once again thanks.